# measure theory and absolute continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a prelim question, I am not sure my approach was correct. Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Let $f$ be an absolutely continuous function on an interval $I$ and $E$ be a subset of $I$ such that $m ( E ) = 0$. Show that $m ( f(E) ) = 0$.

My approach: Assume $m ( f(E) ) > 0$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exist a closed set $K$ such that $K$ is a subset of $f(E)$ and $m ( f(E)/K) < \epsilon$. By noting absolute continuity imply continuity and then taking inverse of $K$ under $f$, we conclude $f^{-1}(K)$ is a subset of $E$. But $f^{-1}(K)$ is a closed set, hence of positive measure so we have a contradiction.

First, I like to know my answer was correct. I also like if you guys can comment on how absolute continuity is being used here. I just used the regular continuity property. I apologize for writing math in words, I am not conversant in latec.

Thank you

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: I fixed your LaTex.  In most cases, simply surrounding the math items with dollar signs (\$...\$) does most of the work.  This was certainly the case with your post.

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken but I don't think $f^{-1}(K)$ being closed implies that it is of positive measure? The standard $\frac{1}{3}$ cantor set is closed and is of zero measure. If the set were open I would think it would necessarily have positive measure.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for pointing it out..

Comment: To prove the statement you should cover the measure $0$ set $E$ by countably many intervals whose union is of small measure. Then replace the previous intervals by disjoint intervals whose union has the same measure as the previous union of intervals. Note that the union of the images of these disjoint intervals provides a covering of $f(E)$. By absolute continuity the measure of $f(E)$ is small since the covering of $E$ has small measure.

Comment: You are absolutely right..I got it..Thanks again! Cheers!